# Matrix norm that keeps order relation when applied to a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $M_{n\times n}$ be the vector space of real square matrices of size $n\times n$. Does there exist a matrix norm $\left\lVert\cdot\right\rVert_M$ such that if $\left\lVert A\right\rVert_M \leq \left\lVert B\right\rVert_M$, then for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\left\lVert Av\right\rVert_2\leq \left\lVert Bv\right\rVert_2$, where $\left\lVert \cdot\right\rVert_2$ is the usual $l^2$ norm over $\mathbb{R}^n$?

This does not work for the induced norm. For example let $A,B$ be

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Then $\left\lVert A\right\rVert_2 = 2 < 4 = \left\lVert B\right\rVert_2$, but consider $v = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $Av = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $Bv = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, so this clearly doesn't work.

Comment: Continue your example: if $w=(0,1)$ then $\|Aw\|_2<\|Bw\|_2$. So whatever matrix norm you would pick either $v$ or $w$ breaks.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Of course, this line of thought slipped my mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When $n>1$, no. Let $A=e_1e_1^T,\,B=ce_2e_2^T$ and $v=e_1$. When $c$ is sufficiently large, we have $\|A\|_M<\|B\|_M$ but $\|Av\|_2=1>0=\|Bv\|_2$.

The answer remains negative even if you require $A$ and $B$ to be invertible. Let $A=\frac{1}{c}I+e_1e_1^T$ and $B=ce_2e_2^T+\frac{1}{c}I$. When $c\to\infty$, we have $\|A\|_M\to\|e_1e_1^T\|_M$ and $\|B\|_M\ge c\|e_2e_2^T\|_M-\frac{1}{c}\|I\|_M\to\infty$. Therefore $\|A\|_M<\|B\|_M$ when $c$ is sufficiently large. Yet, $\|Ae_1\|_2=\frac{1}{c}+1>\frac{1}{c}=\|Be_1\|_2$.